# Approaches to merge two issue tracking lists inside new list

Tags: 2013, list, list-item, issue-tracking, merge

I am working on 5 team sub sites, each sub site have 2 issue tracking lists which are based on 2 different custom content types.

Now our customer asked us to merge these two issue tracking lists into one list, that contain all the items from the two lists. So for example if currently we have 10 items inside the first list and 5 items inside the second list, then the new list will have 15 items.

Now currently I have around 60 items that need to be transferred inside the new list, and I do not want to over-engineer the case . So I am planning to do the following steps:-

- I will create a new list which represents the new list, without any items.
- Then I will manually copy/paste the content from the current 2 lists into the new list.
- I will hide the 2 old lists , so users will be adding /modifying the new list only

Now this should work and it might take around 2 hours to complete which sound valid. But I am trying to find a way how I can preserve the following values inside the new list items:-

- Original created date.
- Original modified date.
- Original created by.
- Original modified by.
- Also the issue tracking list items  have comments inside it, and each comments have created date and created by which i need to preserve the original values of them.
  -final point i  do not have to move the item versions, so having the final version of each item on the new list is acceptable by the customer..

[image]

Comment: Use one of your original lists as 'new' list, saves you half the work. The Created date can be set with (xSOM) code. SharePoint will overwrite any changes to the Modified field, so you would have to go into the database (or hook in at low level)

Comment: @Denny yes this sound valid , i will chose the list that have more items to start with, then i can modify the system generated values.. so you mean i can modify the created date and created by using script,, but the modified date & modified by values will be equal to the user how will do the items merging ? second point what about the comments inside each item (as shown on the picture i provide ) ? is there a way to modify its created & created by values?

Comment: *After* you modify something SP will execute its Modified process and set the Modified date.... comments.. I recall they are hairy to alter.

Comment: @DannyEngelman you are correct now whenever someone edit the item a new comment will be added, even with empty text,, so this will cause a problem in my case ,, so is there a better way to transfer the items so i can preserve all its original values?

Comment: As I said.. SharePoint comments .. hairpulling stuff..So I never did anything other than OOB stuff with them...

Comment: @DannyEngelman let say i manually add the old comments inside the new items, in this case i will end up with having extra unwanted comments with empty text (which will be generated when i transfer the item) and comments containing the original text but with created date and created by user = to the  user who did the transfer... so is there a way to delete unwanted comments + a way to update the created by and created date values for the valid comments ?

Comment: @DannyEngelman i think what u mentioned in this sentence <<"SharePoint will overwrite any changes to the Modified field, so you would have to go into the database (or hook in at low level) ">> is not 100% correct, as i tried this approach http://alexbrassington.com/2013/11/07/changing-modified-and-created-details-in-sharepoint/ and i was able to update the modified date and modified by fields and SharePoint will not override it..

Comment: That's what I meant with lower level... PowerShell, .Net

Comment: @johnG empty comments won't be saved if you can change your comments field to plain text. Obviously, that's always an option, but can be helpful when rich text is unnecessary.